# Sort on none-unique field and pagination mongo

Tags: mongodb, sorting, pagination

If I want to sort by product price, when I apply skip and limit it works if prices are distinct but if they are all the same, pagination breaks (next page result isn't expected, it shows already shown results), as if sorting products is computed differently everytime. So I'm wondering is adding product _id (which is unique) to sort: {product_price:1, product_id:1} correct to ensure that my pagination won't break (so that sort is ordered equally everytime). Is there something else I should be aware?
Thanks

Comment: That should work. Have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem and I can't. Does the query have the same problems on the shell?

Comment: @JM.D Seems it is working, but I asked if maybe I'm not aware of something.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Yes. I have prices all 0, first request: sort: {price: 1}, skip:0, limit:2 and second: sort {price:1}, skip:2, limit:2. I have 4 products total It think it is due to mongo optimization procedure. It doesn't sort in same order everytime if all  product prices are the same. And I forgot to mention I'm using aggregate framework

Comment: @Mata: So please give the complete pipeline.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg

first: db.product.aggregate([{$sort :{price :1}}, {$skip: 0}, {$limit:2}])
second: db.product.aggregate([{$sort :{price :1}}, {$skip: 2}, {$limit:2}] ) Product collection:
{ "_id" : 1, "price" : 0 },
{ "_id" : 2, "price" : 0 },
{ "_id" : 3, "price" : 0 },
{ "_id" : 4, "price" : 0 }
results first: { "_id" : 1, "price" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 2, "price" : 0 } results second: { "_id" : 1, "price" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 3, "price" : 0 }

Comment: The result technically isn't wrong, since all products technically share the same price of 0. So the outcome of the sort is not deterministic. If you set actual values for the price, your aggregates work as expected. Even when the price is 0, you could simply add the _id to the `$sort` step. Note: your aggregates could rather be expressed as queries: `db.product.find().sort({price:1}).skip(x).limit(y)`.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg
I simplified problem I'm sorting on array of objects field, so I'm using aggregate for unwind (which I need to use $match on the result), but problem was the same, ok now I know that adding _id to sort is ok procedure, thx.